# Where is my Azure Web Jobs script located?

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

Is it possible to download the files/scripts of a web job already uploaded into an Azure Web App? If so, where is it located?

Comment: While yes the question is similar, its not direct in the title of the post nor does it specify the path of the web job in its answer. "Azure WebJobs - where hosted?" is very vague and I never found it. The answer provided by dreamgeek was very direct and should help a lot of people very quickly.

Comment: Can you edit your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to d:\home\site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs.... in KUDU site after login azure portal, get script file.
Follow this link for more details
https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/WebJobs